# Stop deallocation of instance variable I need to stay around (but not worthy of being a property)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm currently making block based wrappers around some methods of the Dropbox, Google Drive, and Box.com SDKs. I've successfully wrapped upload functionality into all three, and they all work nicely. The wrappers have a "common" interface that conform to a universal spec among the three services, which is why I'm doing this.

Dropbox is the only one that runs on delegate callbacks. I have no issues with the upload classes. However, I'm trying to implement some download classes in the same manner. I'm running into an issue so far that my returned instances are getting immediately deallocated before any of the delegate methods in the wrapper are called.  First, check out the method structure of the _*working*_ "Upload" class:

```
+(id)uploaderWithPaths:(NSMutableDictionary *)paths 
              progress:(JAUploadProgressBlock)progBlock 
             completed:(JAUploadCompletedBlock)compBlock
                failed:(JAUploadFailedBlock)failBlock;

-(void)upload;

//in .m
return [[[self class] alloc]initWithPaths:paths 
                                 progress:progBlock 
                                completed:compBlock 
                                   failed:failBlock];
-(void)upload {
    //setup Dropbox Rest Client
    //configure delegate, etc
    [dbRestClient doUpload...];
}
//delegate stuff
..onProgress {
self.progressBlock(progress);

..onComplete {
self.completedBlock(info);

..onFailed {
self.failedBlock(error);
```

Thus, instantiating and performing an upload goes like this:

```
JAUploadProgressBlock progress = ^(CGFloat percentage) {
    NSLog(@"%.2f",percentage); }
JAUploadCompletedBlock completed = ^(NSMutableDictionary *info) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@",info); }
JAUploadFailedBlock failed = ^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed: %@",[error localizedDescription];
JAUploadWrapperDropbox *uploader 
     = [JAUploadWrapperDropbox uploaderWithPaths:paths
                                        progress:progress
                                       completed:completed
                                          failed:failed];
[uploader upload];
```

In the upload wrapper class, the instance does not get deallocated immediately, the delegate messages inside the wrapper get called, my block callbacks fire, and everything goes as planned.

**However, my Download wrapper class, which is modeled exactly like the upload wrapper,
gets deallocated before any of the delegate methods in the wrapper are called.**

This class is not conducive to being a property, because it's not suited for re-use. It's really meant to be used once or as one offs. Using a strong property fixes the issue, but like I said, **I don't need to use a property for my upload wrapper class.**

What am I doing wrong?

You can check this project out at https://github.com/justinxxvii/JAOperationWrapper
I did make a commit of the Download wrapper but the headers do not have any documentation yet.

Comment: Usually when I have classes like this for upload/download, I create an NSMutableArray to store instances of the class in, and I remove the object from the array once the process is completed.

Comment: I understand. Would be nice to know why this particular case fails. I haven't even tried wrapping Google Drive or Box.com downloading yet. Haven't made it that far yet

Comment: This project semi-utilizes the same solution you have, I created NSOperation classes for easily queueing uploads in the same uniform manner. By using an NSOperation for the download wrapper I overcome the issue.

Comment: Is the git repo complete? I don't see some of the above code there, so it's hard to diagnose (a) why upload is retaining it; and (b) why download isn't. Seems that you have to understand the object graph and what's keeping the strong reference to the upload object while the upload is in progress and what resolves that strong reference when the upload is done and then diagnose what's different in the download's object graph. I don't think we've got enough code to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Your title says "instance variable" but your code uses a local. Is it in fact an ivar?

Comment: @Rob the git repo is up to date with my current project, except I haven't updated the readme file or added any documentation to the new download wrappers. I'm rethinking the project and will just turn it into something that needs to be retained explicitly. The Google Drive and Box.com SDKs both force this, I don't see why mine should be different. I think that the DropboxSDK is doing something behind the scenes differently in their upload and download logic. Keeping a strong property resolves my issue, so I'll just have to go that way.

Comment: @JoshCaswell you're right, my mistake these are in fact Local Variables.

Comment: @JustinAmberson For what it's worth, I like your idea of abandoning the wrapper concept, and sticking with `NSOperation`-based implementation. It's clean, you can enjoy concurrency, etc.